# How to find the maximum of a prob in PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to solve a linear problem in PuLP that minimizes a cost function.  The cost function is itself a function of the maximum value of the cost function, e.g., I have a daily cost, and I am trying to minimize the monthly cost, which is the sum of the daily cost plus the maximum daily cost in the month.  I don't think I'm capturing the maximum value of the function in the final solution, and I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this issue.  The basic outline of the code is below:

```
# Initialize the problem to be solved
prob = LpProblem("monthly_cost", LpMinimize)

# The number of time steps
# price is a pre-existing array of variable prices
tmax = len(price)
# Time range
time = list(range(tmax))

# Price reduction at every time step
d = LpVariable.dict("d", (time), 0, 5)
# Price increase at every time step 
c = LpVariable.dict("c", (time), 0, 5)

# Define revenues = price increase - price reduction + initial price
revenue = ([(c[t] - d[t] + price[t]) for t in time])
# Find maximum revenue
max_revenue = max(revenue)

# Initialize the problem
prob += sum([revenue[t]*0.0245 for t in time]) + max_revenue

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()
```

The variable max_revenue always equals c_0 - d_0 + price[0] even though price[0] is not the maximum of price and c_0 and d_0 both equal 0.  Does anyone know how to ensure the dynamic maximum is being inserted into the problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do the following in PuLP or any other standard LP solvers:

`max_revenue = max(revenue)`

This is because determining the maximum will require the solver to evaluate `revenue` equations; so in this case, I don't think you can extract a standard LP model. Such models are in fact [non-smooth](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01581628).

In such situations, you can easily reformulate the problem as follows:

`max_revenue >= revenue = ([(c[t] - d[t] + price[t]) for t in time])`

This works, as for any value of `revenue`: `max_revenue >= revenue`. This in turn helps in extracting a standard LP model from the equations. Hence, the original problem formulation gets extended with additional inequality constraints (the equality constraints and the objective functions should be the same as before). So it could look something like this (word of caution: I have not tested this):

```
# Define variable
max_revenue = LpVariable("Max Revenue", 0)

# Define other variables, revenues, etc.

# Add the inequality constraints
for item in revenue:
    prob += max_revenue >= item
```

I would also suggest that you have a look at [scipy.optimize.linprog](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html). PuLP writes the model in an intermediary file, and then calls installed solver to solve the model. On the other hand, in [scipy.optimize.linprog](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) it's all done in python and should be faster. However, if your problem can not be solved using simplex algorithm, or you require other professional solvers (e.g. CPlex, Gurobi, etc.) then PuLP is a good choice.

Also, see the discussion on Data Fitting (page 19) in [Introduction to Linear Optimisation by Bertsimas](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Linear-Optimization-Scientific-Computation/dp/1886529191).

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I suspected there was a mathematical term for this type of modeling, I just hadn't figured it out.

Comment: In regards to the problem reformulation, I don't quite understand where this line would be employed.  Do you propose `max_price >= revenue = ([(c[t] - d[t] + price[t]) for t in time])` as the new problem?  And would max_revenue be a variable?

Comment: Yes, `max_revenue` would be a variable. Then you have another set of inequality constraints in the form of: `max_revenue >= revenue`, alongside the original equality constraints: `revenue = ([(c[t] - d[t] + price[t]) for t in time])`. Sorry it was a bit vague - I have fixed it now. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: It is quite a good answer along with reference links.